# You do not have permissions to access this content in django app?

Tags: python, django

I have got  simple Django app + Mongoengine app from here https://github.com/pydanny/django-mongonaut

I passed all install instructions, but still when trying to access `localhost:8000/mongonaut/` i see

***You do not have permissions to access this content.***

What is the worst  - there is no any login form.

Comment: are you logged in to your account at localhost:8000/admin/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**solve This issue :**

first Login with

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

In case you dont know the user name and password run :

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

then go to

```
127.0.0.1:8000/mongonaut/
```